# Finding in terms of via integration

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> If $\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^ {98}x\,\mathrm dx=A$, find $\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^ {100}x\,\mathrm dx$ in terms of $A$.

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Hint : use that $\sin^{98}(x)\sin^2(x)  = \sin^{98}(x) (1 - \cos^2(x) )$ and then use an integration by parts knowing that  $\frac{(\sin^{99}(x))}{99} '= \sin^{98}\cos(x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $n \in \mathbb{N}, n\ge 3$ we have
\begin{eqnarray}
I_n&:=&\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^n x\,dx=-\int_0^{\pi/2}(\cos x)'\sin^{n-1}x\,dx=(n-1)\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^2x\sin^{n-2}x\,dx\\
&=&(n-1)\int_0^{\pi/2}(1-\sin^2x)\sin^{n-2}x\,dx=(n-1)(I_{n-2}-I_n),
\end{eqnarray}
i.e.
$$
I_n=\frac{n-1}{n}I_{n-2}.
$$
Hence
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{100}x\,dx=I_{100}=\frac{99}{100}I_{98}=\frac{99}{100}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{98}x\,dx=\frac{99}{100}A.
$$

Answer (score 0):

we ll..for such questions ...that is integral involving limits from 0 to pi/2  sin^n(x) we can use wallis formula
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-cDM-xNQK18